# What is the adjective that express the eyes of people who are sick or high on drug?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I suspect my children have some symptom of flu or Covid.

Their eyes are somehow spacing out or lacking vividness or liveliness like some people are high on drug.

**What is the adjective that express the eyes of people who are sick or high on drug?**

For example, *he is bleary-eyed*.

Comment: Perhaps blank eyes?

Comment: The best answers will depend on context.  In a literary work, you might use the expression "dull eyes," but in talking to a doctor trying to diagnose an illness in your child, you would say something more specific.  For instance, some drugs make a child's pupils dilated, and that is exactly what some parents look for in their children when they suspect they have been using drugs.

Comment: [corrections: high on drugs, with an s//What is the adjective that describes the eyes of people who are high on drugs.]

Comment: Dead-eyed sounds a bit too severe?

Answer (score -1):

The common term (at least in AmE) is "**blood shot**" and it is used to describe eyes that are red or irritated. See [blood shot eyes.](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=blood+shot+eyes&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover) (Use discretion, images could be disturbing)

For less intensity issues you could use "**bleary eyes**," "**dreary eyes**," or just "**irritated eyes**." See [bleary eyes](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=bleary-eyed&qpvt=bleary+eyes&form=IGRE&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover) and [dreary eyes.](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=dreary+eyes&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover)

Where I am from we almost always "blood shot" for even the slightest bit of red. And for dreary eyes we use "tired eyes" sometimes as well.

Comment: their eyes are not too red, maybe 10% red but not very red. It is more like tired eyes. Do you think "bleary-eyed" is ok?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that would work, you could also use just "irritated" also. I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: "Blood shot eyes" is commonly used in all varieties of English. Not just American English.

Comment: *Glassy Eyed* is probably the most precise option.  Many of the other options can also be used when someone is tired or groggy but *glassy eyed* means things are not OK.

Comment: Some drugs enlarge the pupils.